# Delete row if the first 4 datarows are empty

Tags: c#

I have a dataTable , in which I want to dynamically delete the row from the dataTable if the datarow[0] to datarow[3] are empty.

I have tried code, but not sure how to delete the row:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
 if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[0].ToString())) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[1].ToString())) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[2].ToString())) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[3].ToString())))
  {
 // delete the Row

    }
 }

myDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

How to delete the row using c# ?

Comment: You have to delete from last row toward the first row.  When you delete row zero than all the other rows index drop by one. So delete row 3, 2,1,0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`row.Delete()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.delete?view=netframework-4.8) - [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZNG1qT).

Normally you can't add to or remove from a collection inside a `foreach` loop, but calling `row.Delete()` only marks the row for deletion. It's not actually deleted until `AcceptChanges` is called.

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Columns.Add("One", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Two", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Three", typeof(string));

dataTable.LoadDataRow(new [] { "", "", ""}, true);
dataTable.LoadDataRow(new [] { "NotBlank", "", ""}, true);
dataTable.LoadDataRow(new [] { "", "", "" }, true);
dataTable.LoadDataRow(new [] { "NotBlank", "", "" }, true);
dataTable.LoadDataRow(new [] { "", "", "" }, true);

dataTable.AcceptChanges();

// 5 rows in table.

foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows) {
    var values = new[] { row[0], row[1], row[2] };
    if(values.All(x => x == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ToString()))) {
        row.Delete();   

    }
}

// Still 5 rows, 3 marked as deleted

dataTable.AcceptChanges();

// 2 rows in table.
```

Comment: You can't do that since you would be modifying the collection being iterated through.

Comment: It turn out you can, since you're not actually modifying the collection until you call `AcceptChanges`. I didn't think it would work, but it did.

Comment: Interesting.  I think that's why we always use DataTable.Rows.Remove, because it's immediate and doesn't require an AcceptChanges.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Linq to give you a List of the qualifying rows and then delete those rows from the DataTable:

```
var rows = myDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                .Where(r => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[0].ToString())) 
                   && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[1].ToString())) 
                   && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[2].ToString())) 
                   && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(r[3].ToString())))
                .ToList();
            foreach(DataRow row in rows)
            {
                myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(row);
            }
```

Remember to add a reference to System.Linq if you don't have one.